# Creating Message Boxes

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010, I need to have a Message Box pop-up when the user selects specific text (Real Estate) in a combo-box (ProductType).

In short...if the [ProductType] entered by the user is any one of the multiple "Real Estate" options available, then show a Message Box that states "USER MUST COMPLETE RESPA TRACKING" and then direct them to that page (tab) to complete additional text fields.

I've attached the following code to the BEFORE UPDATE function of the combo box.  But that only creates the message, it does not direct them to the tab/fields that need to be entered.

```vb
Private Sub ProductType2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Dim strPrompt As String

strPrompt = "The Product Type selected is Real Estate.  The RESPA Tracking tab MUST be completed at time of App Entry and validated during Underwriting."
If Not IsNull(Me.ProductType2.Value) Then
    If Me.ProductType2.Value Like "Real Estate*" Then
        Cancel = (MsgBox(strPrompt, vbOK) = vbNo)
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what is your vba so far for your combo box? this is possible.  have you tried anything yet? if so can you show us what you have attempted? You can either do it on the change event, the after update event or use a button to trigger the event.  That part is up to you. Please provide more info about what you have done / when you want to trigger the event.

Comment: Thank you @TheGambill, I've edited my question to include the code that I do have.  That code does create the pop-up message, but it I can't figure out how to get it to automatically take them them to the tab/fields that need to be entered.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've solved the creating a `MsgBox` issue, and now your remaining challenge is to *"direct them to the tab/fields that need to be entered"*.

Use the `SetFocus` method to place focus on a specific page in your tab control, or on a control within that page.

This command button example shifts focus to the first control on a page named *Page1* ...

```vb
Private Sub cmdPage1_Click()
    Me!Page1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

But my guess is you will prefer focus on a specific control within the page.  My *Page1* contains a text box named *txtMemo_field*.  This version places the focus on that text box.  Notice the page name is not mentioned in this version; `SetFocus` is called on the text box directly ...

```vb
Private Sub cmdPage1_Click()
    Me!txtMemo_field.SetFocus
End Sub
```